# Which function would be called if a function template exists that could match another overloaded function?

Tags: c++

In C++, say you have two function definitions:

```
template <typename T>
T square (T num);
```

And

```
double square(double num);
```

and you have a function call like:

```
square(1.5);
```

which function would be called?  Which does the compiler choose?

Comment: Why not compile it and see?

Comment: I was having a compiler issue when trying to use the template function that I couldn't figure out.  I just started learning about templates.

Comment: You have to use `square<double>(1.5);` to call the template version with double, else the regular function is chosen (with double argument)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case C++ always prefers non-template version of function as it could easily promote float to double.

Had you used this:-

```
float p = 2.2;
square(p);
```

compiler would have chosen template version in its venture for perfect match.

Comment: It might be prudent to note that the literal `1.5` is interpreted as a `double`, so his second function will be called. If he defined the second `square` to take a float, the template would be used.

Comment: "as it could easily promote float to double" - what do you mean?

Comment: I mean if you call square(1.5), compiler has two options, either treat it as float OR double. But float would require it to instantiate template. So, it would go for double...Please let me know if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The argument `1.5` is of type `double` so it exactly matches both the template and non-template. In such a case the non-template function will be preferred according to [over.best.match] in the standard:

> ... `F1` is defined to be a *better* function than ... `F2` if ... `F1` is not a function template specialization and `F2` is a function template specialization ...

If you called `square` with an `int` or `float` argument, the template would again give an exact match but you'd need a conversion or promotion for the non-template. The template would be selected since it's a better match.

Answer (score 1):

Since call syntax matches the non-template function, so it will be called